# Loss Function vs. Penalty vs. Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

Suppose I want to maximize $u=c_1+c_2$ subject to a budget constraint $p_1c_1+p_2c_2\leq m$ and a requirement $c_2<\overline{c_2}$ that *must* be satisfied. The source of the $c_2<\overline{c_2}$ requirement is not important but you can think of it as a physical or legal limitation that makes it impossible to consume $\overline{c_2}$ or more.

I can write this problem as

$\max\limits_{c_1,c_2} \Big\{(c_1+c_2) -\lambda(p_1c_1+p_2c_2-m)-\rho (c_2-\overline{c_2})\Big\}$ where $\rho=\begin{cases}\infty & \text{if $c_2 \geq\overline{c_2}$}\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

**My question is what do you call $\rho$?** It isn't a Lagrange multiplier like $\lambda$ because the value of $\rho$ is fixed exogenously by the modeler. But it functions similarly in that it penalizes violation of the constraint. Would you call it a loss function? A penalty?

Comment: Mathematically $\overline c_2$ is a parameter like $p_1, p_2$ and $m$. And I wouldn´t assume that $\rho$ is fixed and I would call it a Lagrange multiplier as well. To solve such problems you have to apply the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: I am not assuming $\rho$ is fixed. I am hardcoding it to be $\infty$ or 0 in my simulation precisely so that it will be impossible for the agent to break the constraint. $\overline{c_2}$ is different than the other parameters in the sense that I'm fixing it. To clarify let the constraint be $c_2< 100$.

Comment: If you use KKT then the condition is fulfilled.